# How to multithread line by line pixels using std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to learn how to adapt pseudocode I have for multithreading line by line to C++. I understand the pseudocode but I am not very experienced with C++ nor the `std::thread` function.

This is the pseudocode I have and that I've often used:

```
myFunction
{
    int threadNr=previous;
    int numberProcs = countProcessors();

    // Every thread calculates a different line
    for (y = y_start+threadNr; y < y_end; y+=numberProcs) {
        // Horizontal lines
        for (int x = x_start; x < x_end; x++) {
            psetp(x,y,RGB(255,128,0));
        }
    }
}

int numberProcs = countProcessors();

// Launch threads: e.g. for 1 processor launch no other thread, for 2 processors launch 1 thread, for 4 processors launch 3 threads
for (i=0; i<numberProcs-1; i++)
    triggerThread(50,FME_CUSTOMEVENT,i); //The last parameter is the thread number

triggerEvent(50,FME_CUSTOMEVENT,numberProcs-1); //The last thread used for progress

// Wait for all threads to finished
waitForThread(0,0xffffffff,-1);
```

I know I can call my current function using one thread via `std::thread` like this:

```
        std::thread t1(FilterImage,&size_param, cdepth, in_data, input_worldP, output_worldP);
        t1.join();
```

But this is not efficient as it is calling the entire function over and over again per thread.

I would expect every processor to tackle a horizontal line on it's own.

Any example code would would be highly appreciated as I tend to learn best through example.

Comment: Do not immediately `join` a thread. The caller will block and wait for the thread to complete and at that point you've pretty much wasted the thread because the two threads are running serially. Instead hold off on joining until the caller is done its work or has to wait for the thread to finish (Look at `std::future` for a better way to handle this second case).

Comment: Maybe consider looking at **OpenMP** which has a `parallel for` that does all the hard work for you and is configurable in the number of threads even at runtime and is efficient and well tested. It just looks like a single comment to compilers that don't understand it so your code works even on platforms that don't have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking `thread::join()` forces the calling thread to wait for the child thread to finish executing. For example, if I use it to create a number of threads in a loop, and call `join()` on each one, it'll be the same as though everything happened in sequence.

Here's an example. I have two methods that print out the numbers 1 through n. The first one does it single threaded, and the second one joins each thread as they're created. **Both have the same output, but the threaded one is slower because you're waiting for each thread to finish before starting the next one.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void printN_nothreads(int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}

void printN_threaded(int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::thread t([=](){ std::cout << i << "\n"; });
        t.join(); //This forces synchronization
    }
}
```

**Doing threading better.**

To gain benefit from using threads, you have to start all the threads before joining them. In addition, to avoid [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing), each thread should work on a separate region of the image (ideally a section that's far away in memory).

Let's look at how this would work. I don't know what library you're using, so instead I'm going to show you how to write a multi-threaded transform on a vector.

```
auto transform_section = [](auto func, auto begin, auto end) {
    for(; begin != end; ++begin) {
        func(*begin);
    }
};
```

This `transform_section` function will be called once per thread, each on a different section of the vector. Let's write `transform` so it's multithreaded.

```
template<class Func, class T>
void transform(Func func, std::vector<T>& data, int num_threads) {
    size_t size = data.size(); 
    auto section_start = [size, num_threads](int thread_index) {
        return size * thread_index / num_threads; 
    };
    auto section_end = [size, num_threads](int thread_index) {
        return size * (thread_index + 1) / num_threads; 
    };

    std::vector<std::thread> threads(num_threads); 

    // Each thread works on a different section
    for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        T* start = &data[section_start(i)];
        T* end   = &data[section_end(i)]; 

        threads[i] = std::thread(transform_section, func, start, end);
    }

    // We only join AFTER all the threads are started
    for(std::thread& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, J Antonio Perez, for your detailed reply. I will have to study your example carefully to understand it better. But I see the logic.